# Multi selection image from gallery is not working in some mobiles in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I'm using EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE request to select multiple images from Gallery.
When am running the same app in my One plus it is working fine and able to choose multiple images.
Unable toselect multiple images from Gallery in Samsung M20.
I did research a lot, but unable to find it.
( But able to Multi select images from "Photos" thru both mobiles)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int BROWSE_RESULT = 1;
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    ArrayList<Uri> imagesUri = new ArrayList<>();
    GridView gridView;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button btn_browse,btn_delete;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gridView= findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        btn_browse = findViewById(R.id.btn_browse);

        btn_browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                f_openImageExplorer();
            }
        });
    }

    public void f_openImageExplorer() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
       // startActivityForResult(intent, BROWSE_RESULT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), BROWSE_RESULT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == BROWSE_RESULT) {
            if (resultCode == MainActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,Integer.toString(resultCode) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    int imageCount = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                    for(int i = 0; i< imageCount;i++){
                        Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                        imagesUri.add(imageUri);
                        imageAdapter= new ImageAdapter(getBaseContext(), imagesUri);
                        gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
                        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Uri singleImageUri = data.getData();
                    imagesUri.add(singleImageUri);
                    ImageAdapter imageAdapter= new ImageAdapter(getBaseContext(), imagesUri);
                    gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
                    imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` is a request, not a command. There is no requirement for every `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activity to honor `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`.

Comment: @CommonWare thanks for swift reply, means should i remove that ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

Comment: No, it just means that you should not expect the user to always be able to select multiple items.

Comment: Yeah correct!, As per my current requirement user wanted to select multi images from Gallery.

Comment: Did you get the answer for this? If yes, please tell me also.